# gitleaks in gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I am attempting to manually setup gitleaks in GitLab CI to scan my GitLab repo for secrets. I think I've misconfigured my job. The job passes, but outputs a `unknown flag 'c'` and the gitleaks help dialogue but no expected actual gitleaks-based output.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml' looks like:

```
stages:
  - security

gitleaks:
  stage: security
  image: zricethezav/gitleaks
  script:
    - gitleaks --verbose --repo-path=$PWD
```

Any suggestion where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if [this example works better](https://cylab.be/blog/20/avoid-leaking-secrets-in-your-gitlab-repository)

```
stages:
  - leaks
  - test

leaks:gitleaks:
  stage: leaks
  image: 
    name: "zricethezav/gitleaks"
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - gitleaks -v --repo-path=./ --config=gitleaks.toml
```

You can adapt the stage name, but adding an empty entrypoint, and a [config file](https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks/blob/065b6216049d71e7f3c28dec3f4e93a24b304033/gitleaks.toml) might help.

---

Note that with [GitLab 14.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/01/22/gitlab-14-7-released/#major-gitleaks-performance-improvements) (January 2022), there has been some major Gitleaks performance improvements.

> Building on the [large rule expansion included in GitLab 14.5](/releases/2021/11/22/gitlab-14-5-released/#additional-secret-detection-pattern-support), we are updating our [GitLab Secret Detection analyzer](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/secret_detection/), [Gitleaks](https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks), to the next major version 8.
>
> This new, major version includes massive performance updates and a [complete rewrite](https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks/releases/tag/v8.0.0) of its core detection engine.
>
> Secret Detection historical scans should now run much faster, with a large reduction in memory usage.
> This means both faster detection and shorter (and more efficient) pipelines.
> This change also sets us up to make more performance improvements that will improve all non-historical Secret Detection job runs in the future.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/analyzers) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/345770).

Comment: Yessssssss! Thank you!